# Can a Half Orc Barbarian use Relentless Endurance after failing to use Relentless Rage?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, racial-traits, half-orc

Relentless Rage allows you to avoid passing out with a successful Constitution saving throw.

> Starting at 11th level, your rage can keep you fighting despite grievous wounds. If you drop to 0 hit points while you're raging and don't die outright, you can make a DC 10 Constitution saving throw. If you succeed, you drop to 1 hit point instead.

A Half-Orc's Relentless Endurance allows you to do the same.

> When you are reduced to 0 hit points but not killed outright, you can drop to 1 hit point instead. You can't use this feature again until you finish a long rest.

As a Half-Orc Barbarian, after failing to come back to 1 hit point using your Relentless Rage can you immediately try to do the same using Relentless Endurance?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's go through the process in which this is important. You're a Half-Orc Barbarian, you're raging and reduced to 0hp but not killed outright. What happens?

1. You can use Relentless Endurance. In this case there are no variables, you're just back at 1hp and continue fighting with your unused Relentless Rage ready to go in case of another close brush with death.
2. You can use Relentless Rage instead. In this case, if you succeed on the Constitution saving throw, you're back at 1hp and continue fighting. If you fail that saving throw, however, **you're still in the moment of  "reduced to 0hp but not killed outright"**, which to me means that you can use Relentless Endurance, or any other ability usable at that state. (Samurai's Strength Before Death is an example)

Neither of those abilities requires any sort of action or reaction to use them, so in principle there should be no limits to how many of them you can use at an opportune moment.

Comment: I agree. It might also be worth noting that it is probably not at all overpowered to allow this since relentless endurance is a 1/long rest ability.

Comment: Hmmm, the contrast given by the other answer makes me hesitate which one I should accept. I'll wait a bit further.

Comment: It's generally courteous to wait a day before accepting an answer anyway, so don't rush. And in the end, the ruling at your table is yours to make :)

Answer (score 0):

TBH I think it depends on the DM and if the " dying- Dropping to 0 HP" is instant or over a period of time, and if consciousness and " will" remain active..
Also Endurance will allow you to be conscious and active, but without the increased energy / activity level of Rage.
If the death ( Drop to 0 HP)  is instant, there is no time to make the second action. If there is a duration of " HP dropping to 0 " I think there could maybe a second set of " rolls" / Saves. Slim odds, but hey, Hail Mary anyone?

Comment: You may want to replace "dying" and "death" with "dropping to 0hp" because they are very different things in 5e.

Comment: Agreed and will do so - Old guy that I am i have never even opened a book newer than second / second and a half.. Life happened.. My curiosity got the better of me when I was looking at some Microsoft Exchange Server related topics..

Comment: No worries thanks for dropping by and giving us your answer! If you have time, I'd recommend taking our [tour] (which only takes a minute or two) to learn a bit more about the site and to earn you a badge.

Comment: Hope that my thoughts remain relevant even though I have been out of the game for a long while..

Comment: I think this answer is pretty good, just note that on this site we do require answers to reference official rules and experience in answers so you may find a need to crack open those books if you want to answer other questions. Answers which do not cite rules or are opinions are a good way to quickly earn downvotes. :)